# Safari 6: -webkit-transform: rotateY Bug?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, safari

I upgraded to Mountain Lion yesterday, which includes Safari 6.
Unfortunately, it have some weird -webkit-transform bugs?

Check this url:
http://dropshado.ws/post/1301087289/webkit-transform-perspective-function

Safari 6 shows this (nothing at all...):

[image]

And Chrome shows this (the right way):

[image]

Does anyone have these problems too?

Comment: We're having a similar problem with changing margins. `-webkit-transition: margin-left 0.1s ease-in-out` exists, nothing happens. Remove that style and margin changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been having the same problems with any rotations about the X or Y axis in Safari 6 (running Mountain Lion). The latest webkit build doesn't seem to have any problems, so this must be a bug.

The odd thing is that if you select the element that should have had a transform applied from the DOM tree in the Web Inspector, it highlights the element as if the correct transform has been applied.

Many examples around the web still render correctly in Safari 6, so perhaps there is more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: I just downloaded the last nightly webkit build. Now i works again :)

Answer (score 2):

Was having this problem on my company's website and figured out with my co-worker that adding `overflow: hidden` to the container div seems to fix the issue in Safari 6 on mountain lion.

Works on our site and your example. Strange!